# JQ error, elements dont hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<style>
.download-link {display: none;}
</style>
<a class="download-link">Click here</a>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCxud25S6FNfZ2mN5ZHUg0kA" data-layout="default" data-count="hidden"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function(){
  $( ".g-ytsubscribe" ).click(function() {
  $( ".download-link" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make it so basically people can only see my download link once they have clicked on my subscribe button, but when I do this my subscribe button becomes invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Your script was a little wrong, you're missing a closing bracket at the end with the way you initially had it. However, 'show' doesn't need 'slow' with it, or the function muddled in with it. `show` will just set `display: block`, `opacity: 1`, and `pointer-events: auto`. What you might want is `fadeIn('slow')`  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".g-ytsubscribe" ).click(function() {
  $( ".download-link" ).fadeIn('slow');
 });
});
```

Unless you're wanting other things in along with the click function, then you'd have them as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".g-ytsubscribe" ).click(function() {
  $( ".download-link" ).fadeIn('slow');
  // other stuff in here
 });
});
```

Edit:

And if it was me, I'd have my script as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".download-link" ).hide();

 $( ".g-ytsubscribe" ).click(function() {
  $( ".download-link" ).fadeIn('slow');
  // other stuff in here
 });
});
```

That way you don't need to set the container to display:none in the css.

Edit: [Working pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzYOyy)

You were missing the opening `body` tag, so the markup wouldn't work. I've cleaned up the markup so that in the pen here it's just your button div and the click here link.

Comment: @Olar   your markup is broken in your example too. I've cleaned it up a lot here in this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzYOyy